# Giving for an argument to split and remove the newline character from state using the string method strip

Tags: python, string, split

Getting an error for too many values to unpack. Giving for an argument to split and remove the newline character from the state using the string method strip

```
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

```
def open_file_read(filename):
    try:
        file = open(filename,'r')
    except:
        print("couldn't find file")
    return file
def cities_dictionary_create(file):
    cities = {}
    for line in file:
        city, state = line.split() # ERROR HERE
        new_state = state.strip()
        print(city, state)
        
def print_cities(dict):
    pass
def print_city_count(dict):
    pass

file   = open_file_read("cities.csv")
cities = cities_dictionary_create(file)
if cities:
    print_cities(cities)
    print()
    print_city_count(cities)
```

Comment: You should decide for one version of Python, either 2.7 or 3.x line in the tags.

Comment: Add a debug print just before the failing line that does a test split `print(line, line.split())` . Maybe you have a city with spaces in the name.

Comment: Once you have the failing line, you could post an example CSV of just a few lines that also fails. We can use that for an answer. Likely you should use the `csv` module instead of `line.split()`. Its built to read CSV files (kinda makes sense, that!).

Comment: You have problems parsing data... but won't show us what the data is. This question needs to be closed until you post a sample. if its a CSV file, str.split is not the tool for the job.

Answer (score 1):

The `line.split()` returns a `list` of values, and in this situation the list contains more than `2` values to unpack and assign into the `city` and `state` variables.

Comment: I don't understand it evenly, Could you able provide with editing scripts?

Comment: I've updated the answer. and editing scripts in stackoverflow are not available for `python` lang.

Comment: Could you able to edit my own scripts on the top, which part should be added?

Comment: please `print` what `line.split()` returns. I don't have access to your file.

Comment: I'm trying to join, but apparently I can't. let's try a google meet.

Comment: We don't know what OP's data looks like. using split on a standard csv file is not right. We need sample data posted in the question before we can give a sane answer.

Comment: Hi @ColinKazim , How are you doing brother? Have you done assignment successfully? BTW, I will be so delighted if you give my answer an upvote  or choose it as the correct answer ✅. Looking forward to your response. Cheers 